# If $G$ is a group with $\vert G\vert = 2s$, and $G$ has a conjugacy class of size $s$, then $s$ is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that if $G$ is a group with $\vert G\vert = 2s$, and $G$ has a
>   conjugacy class of size $s$, then $s$ is odd.

How do I go about proving this? 
The remaining classes must partition $s$ elements of $G$ and must have a size which divides $s$, but how does this help prove that $s$ is odd? I tried to see if the class formula would be useful, but to no avial.

Comment: So $G$ has an element $x$ of order $2$ with centralizer of order $2$. Now $x$ is contained in some Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$. If $|S| \ge 4$ then, since $S$ has nontrivial centre, we have  $|C_S(s)| \ge 4$. So $|S|=2$ and $s$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements in a conjugacy class $S$ is equal to the index of the centralizer of any element in $S$.
This means that there exists $a\in G$ so that its centralizer $C(a)$ has index $s$, which implies that its centralizer only has two elements, $0$ and $a$ itself. Now if $s$ wasn't odd $C(a)$ would be contained in a 2-Sylow group of order $\geq 4$. Since $C(a)$ is generated by $a$ we have: $$N(C(a))=N(\langle a\rangle)=C(a)$$
Where $N()$ is the normalizer of a subgroup. This is an absurd since the 2-Sylow is a p-group and any of its proper subgroups has normalizer that strictly contains the group itself. Since the normalizer of the subgroup in the 2-Sylow is contained in the normalizer of the subgroup in $G$ it would need to be contained in $C(a)=\langle a\rangle$. It should be noted that the second equality is true since $a$ has order $2$, in general it isn't.